# Why would a black hole evaporate?

Tags: black-holes, hawking-radiation, virtual-particles

Hawking radiation doesn't make sense to me, with respect to black holes getting smaller.

It would seem that any particle (or anti-particle) leaving the Schwartzchild radius would have a similar anti-particle (or particle) similarly entering the black hole as well.  So, over time, I don't see how the blackhole would eventually disappear.

Any particles leaving the radius would be matched by similar particles entering the blackhole.  What am I missing here?